# How to sort on a derived column in IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a column that needs to be derived from the result set that IQueryable returns. Also I want to Sort on that Column. How can I do this ??

```
var opportunities = this.GetUserOpportunitiesByQuery(request, statusOpp)
                .Include(x => x.CompanyId__Parent)
                .Include(x => x.ApprovalStatus__Parent)
                .Include(x => x.OpportunityStatus)
                .Include(x => x.MeetingType__Parent);
```

On Columns that are present in the result we sort on them like this:-

```
var sortBy = request.SortBy?.FirstOrDefault();
    if (sortBy != null)
    {
        var asc = sortBy.Direction == SortingDirection.Ascending;
        switch (sortBy.PropertyName.ToLower())
        {
            case "name":
                opportunities = asc
                    ? opportunities.OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                    : opportunities.OrderByDescending(c => c.Name);
                break;


var results = opportunities.Skip(request.Skip).Take(request.Take).ToList();
```

I need to do the same as above with a derived column. I can have a function that will derive and call it. I am just not clear on how we can do this.

I know I can do .ToList() and calculate the derived column and sort on it. But I think that would sort the query in-memory. Can I do this with IQueryable.

Comment: You can't because the database knows nothing about your function. You will need to do it in memory.

Comment: @RicardoPeres - So how can I make Iqueryable execute and then work on derived column. Does .ToList() execute it ??

Comment: Yes, it executes on the database and then materializes the result.